# mysql not updating rows from temporary table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Provision` with this structure:

```
ONT_ID varchar(12) PK
neID set('7360-1','7360-2','7360-3','5000-1','5000-2') not null
```

and some other crap

I have loaded a temporary table called `tempTable` that has the same structure and the same data. Prior to trying what I'm trying the `neID` in the `Provision` table was a `varchar` field. The values that were not the same as the set were deleted. (I've done this before without a problem.)

Neither this:

```
UPDATE Provision P 
INNER JOIN tempTable TT ON TT.ONT_ID = P.ONT_ID
SET P.neID = TT.NE_ID
```

Nor this (broken up for readability):

```
update Provision P 
set P.neID = ( 
select TT.NE_ID from tempTable TT where TT.ONT_ID = P.ONT_ID 
)
```

...accomplishes what they are supposed to. What is going on?

The `Provision` table has a record of the `ONT_ID` and the `neID` is an empty string. The temp table has the same `ONT_ID` and a pertinent `NE_ID`. I'm trying to update the `neID` in the `Provision` table with the value that is in the temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Data in `tempTable` was wrong. Changed data and updated `Provision` table.